# How Does Firebase Analytics Define Active User?

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics, active-users

This question is for basic Firebase Analytics integration where a dependency is added and nothing else.

How does Firebase Analytics define Active User - does Firebase Analytics count active users as: **foreground users** as in users who actually opened the app OR **background** as well (for example if app has background process that runs daily without UI)?

Answer (score 1):

An active user has engaged with an app in the device foreground, and has logged a user_engagement event.

The documentation is here:
https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6317517#active-users